# jQuery hover problems: 1. z-index? 2. unbind/rebind?

Tags: jquery, hover, z-index, unbind

Let me know if this should really be asked as two separate problems, but as it deals with the same chunk of code (in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jhacks/xCcdn/89/), I felt it'd be best for one topic. Let me know if I should edit and make it into two. Anyhow, hopefully you can look at the code... the following problems I'm having:

1. Z-index. So, As you will see in the code, when you hover over the divs, the red topIconNew div doesn't stay stationary, but I'd like it to. I realize that this is because it is below the topTip and topDrop div in the html, so when they show up, it moves with them. However, I have to place it below these divs in the html, as it is positioned relative, so get it to position itself consistently whether or not the topIconNew div is present, it needs to be first in the html. I thought perhaps I could get this all working by using z-index, but CSS is not enough here. Is there something to change in the jQuery?
2. Unbind/rebind. In the jQuery code, I have .unbind("hover") upon clicking topIconNew to get the topTip and topDrop divs to show. I want the hover disabled when the topTip and topDrop divs are showing. However, when trying to use .rebind("hover") within the .click(document) function, it still won't work. What is the best way to approach this temporary disabling of .hover?

Also in regards to hover: if you were to remove the .unbind("hover") line of code, you will notice that the hovering behaves strangely when the topTip/topDrop divs are showing. The other hover topTip div won't hide when moving the pointer off, the div becomes permanent. It would be nice for there an option of hover to still work properly while the topTip/topDrop divs are present (rather than the approached mentioned above at temporarily disabling hover). I'd want the hovering divs to of course always be BELOW the topTip/TopDrop divs that were open though.

Anyways, if my questions and/or code is unclear, just let me know. Also, I'm fine with creating another post separating these questions as well if that'd be better. Anyway, any and all help is appreciated... Thanks!!!

Also (and not as important because think I can figure out where I went wrong), why isn't my .css('background-color:#555555') working?

Comment: This is a *huge* amount of text/code to look through. I doubt your question will get answered. Can you condense it into a simple test case that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Will do... I thought as much. I will work at getting it easier to answer, and likely just split it up into 2 questions. Thanks for the heads up with that.

Comment: I do think you should split the questions. And also, what exactly is it you're trying to accomplish here? I took a look at your code, and I can't figure out what the end result is supposed to do. I take it topTip is a custom tooltip, but by the time you get to topDrop you've lost me. And what's topiconNew for?

Comment: Essentially, the topIcon is a navigational icon while the topIconNew is a notification icon. When you click the navigational icon, it brings you to X page. When you hover topIcon, the topTip (it will be a tooltip) shows, when you click topIconNew, the tooltip expands and a dropdown (topDrop) shows up to show your notifcations. That is the essence of what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have time to give a complete answer to both questions, but I do have a simple answer for this part:

> What is the best way to approach this temporary disabling of .hover?

My preferred method is to have a `hoverEnabled` variable and leave the hover handler permanently bound - here's a very generic example (substitute your own selectors and processing):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var hoverEnabled = true;

   $("someselector").hover(
      function() {
         if (!hoverEnabled)
            return;

         // actual mouse enter processing here
      },
      function() {
         if (!hoverEnabled)
            return;

         // actual mouse leave processing here
      }
   );

   $("someotherselector").on("some event", function() {
      hoverEnabled = false;
   });

   $("someotherselector").on("some other event", function() {
      hoverEnabled = true;
   });
});
```

Obviously this technique works for any event that you want to temporarily disable (and can also be used to temporarily "disable" `setInterval` processing), and of course you don't have to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), you can use `.click()` or whatever is appropriate.